# Loop through certain files in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a directory that contains .sql files like

```
file.xxx.v3.0.sql
file.xxx.v3.0.sql
file.xxx.v3.0.sql
file.xxx.v3.0.sql
```

In a .bat file how would I loop through all the files in a directory that start with "file." and end in ".v3.0.sql"?

So far I've got

```
for /f %%b in ('dir /b /s "%apppath%\files\*.sql"') do call :import %%b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forego the `for /f` route. There be dragons (for Unicode characters and spaces, especially – best not pick up any bad habits).

You can use plain old `for`, which can iterate over files just fine:

```
for %%b in (%apppath%\files\file.*.v3.0.sql) do (
  call :import %%b
)
```

Comment: +1 Do not forget to mention the dragons that exist with just the plain `for` loop.  (Files modified during the loop may be processed twice).  There be dragons hiding in all the commands of cmd.exe **:)**

Comment: Well, it's not very wise to modify a collection you're iterating, in any language ;)

Comment: Agreed, but some people will still try to nonetheless. **:P**

Answer (score 2):

This should work in your case:

```
for /f %%b in ('dir /b /s "%apppath%\files\file.*.v3.0.sql"') do call :import %%b
```

You can also use braces like this:

```
for /f %%b in ('dir /b /s "%apppath%\files\file.*.v3.0.sql"') do (
    call :import %%b
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks, is it also possible to use braces like `for /f %%b in ('dir /b /s "%apppath%\files\file.*.v3.0.sql"') do(::Processing goes here)`